# How to wipe out the existing data in mysql using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, mysql, selenium

Hi I am using excel to do data-driven testing in selenium webdriver with testNG. every time I need to delete the old data in DB as it was stored already just because of me as I tested with the same data periodically. But manually deleting old data in db before testing scripts, looks cumbersome. Is there any way to code in selenium, which is automatically delete the old record in DB before executing scripts. so we can use the same data at any time without deleting data manuallly. Please advise me if you have any idea

Answer (score 1):

You can execute Mysql queries by using JDBC(Java Database Connectivity) api which defines how a client may access a database.You have to download MySQL Connector Jar which is the official JDBC driver for MySQL and add it in your class path and before starting the test run the code(in the beforesuite or beforeclass as per your requirement)

```
  Connection conn = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
   try{
      // Register JDBC driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

      //Open a connection
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

      //Execute a query
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
      String sql = "DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id = idno"          
      stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

      rs.close();
}
```

Hope this helps you..Kindly get back if you have any queries

Comment: @anitha k...if you wish to delete all records use TRUNCATE tablename this will delete all records in the table forgot to add that...if you have any queries kindly get back

Comment: @anitha It depends on your site if you have option of deleting records in ur site ex scenario: order page where all orders are listed if there is an option to delete orders there like delete button then you could delete  orders by using selenium script as well by clicking on delete button on all orders but if u have large test data then it will take more time to delete records doing it by executing DB queries will save time

Comment: @anitha If you wish to delete selected records then the simplest way would be you have to keep count of how many entries you add write it to a file then execute the below query

Comment: Yeah thats cool explanation. Unfortunately I have no option for deletion in my web app except one or two. So I think I should go for the way which you told.

Comment: @anitha DELETE FROM TABLENAME ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10                        This will delete the last 10 entries ordering is done by id in descending order you can change it to any other field as per your requirement.Kindly get back if you have any queries

Comment: Hi vicky.. I am unable to get the soln using jdbc driver. Can you please help me?

Comment: Is it possible to delete records without giving ID?? but I need to delete last records which is entered by me through Automation Testing.

Comment: @anithav You got to use any one column to get the last records.If id is the primary key (auto increment )in the table then go for it or if u have date time column or any other primary key then u can also go for it .It is based on ur table structure.                                                                             DELETE FROM tablename ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1 .In this case if ur id is auto increment then it will delete the last record

Comment: I used primary key Id to delete record.but ID may change ryt? i.5) if you delete a row 5 manually, and write query delete from table where id=5, it wont work.becos there is no record in it.In tat case, do I need to check the DB manually everytime? before run the test case?? looks like tiresome process

Comment: @anithav no in the above query u r not deleting by using id = 5 u r just sorting the table in descending order by using id column ex : 10,9,8,7...etc and then deleting the first record in this case( id 10).if ur id is auto increment then obviously 10 will be ur last id u need not hardcore it or look for it manually in db. Change LIMIT to 10 if you want to delete last 10 records

Comment: yeah thats okay man..I can understand. when I mention ID in query ex: delete from tablename where id=10, before that I need to check whether id 10 is avail in DB or not right? it may or may not be available.if someone is deleted that 10th record, then that query will throw error like "10th record is not avail". In this case how will you handle?

Comment: So I think, in this case, we should not go for ID. coz ID may or may not be available. so as you said, we should follow DELETE FROM tablename ORDER BY ID DESC this query. i think this will be better. in this case, we r not selecting record based on Id. so error will not thrown up..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try another aproach. A script or test program that uses selenium but before deletes data in the database.

For example on a recent project that uses maven our java tests are launched by a script that first wipes the database and then rebuilds it all using ous migration scripts. This script can be a bash script (we use it with jenkins) that relies on maven for dropping and creating the database using [flyway](http://flywaydb.org/).
Later, using maven, we launch tests. In every test execution a beforeTest() and afterTest() methods are run at the begining and end of the test.

1. beforeTest() usually writes in the database the data needed for this test.
2. afterTest() usually wipes data in order to left database clean for the next test execution.

Creating and deleting data is made throug DAO or Services classes of the project used inside of the both methods.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Woow..nice explanation. but can you provide me more detail?? about how to write script to wipe out the data ??@Vicky said to me to write class for querying data and deleting data..

Comment: Your explanation looks good. but now the problem is I am using neither Ant nor Maven. So I dont knw how to follow your steps.then what is that our migration script??

Comment: Migration scripts are bassically database creation scripts. This scripts are managed by a external tool for example flyway (http://flywaydb.org/). You can use flyway from the command line if you want. The idea behind this way of work is to deal with database modifications along the project's life. For example you have a basic script for the main tables, later you need to modify one table to add one column so you add a new migration, later you need to add another table then you add a new migration, and so on.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot man..let me check it out. but most of the ppl prefer to do db testing with java using jdbc conn. first time i here about external tool

Comment: Ok, it's easier that way when the project you work is not changing and/or evolving the db schema. But when a project grows it's usefull to let a tool do this work for you. Flyway is a java developed tool and integrates fine with ant or maven. You can also take a look to liquibase (http://www.liquibase.org/).

Comment: Thanks a lot man..let me check it out..I understand that why you suggested me to look at flyway tool.  let me check it out